# gitlab CI: Set cache to be saved locally when distributed cache is enabled

Tags: python, caching, gitlab-ci

I want to be able to configure my cache to be saved locally.
The runner is configured with distributed cache to s3 and I can't find a way to have specific jobs using local cache.

I have a lot of Python dependencies and pipelines that run all the time. I want to make the jobs run much faster and downloading from cloud storage doesn't do the job well enough (also it costs money to download so much data).